# Как в MySQL изменить тип столбца c TEXT на INTEGER с корректным переводом текста в числа?

Tags: mysql, table, insert, type-conversion

В таблице есть столбец типа TEXT в котором записаны целые числа, но с разделителем тысяч, т.е. не `1234`, а `1,234`.

Я хочу сделать столбец типа INTEGER, подскажите как это можно сделать наиболее правильным путем?

По идее я могу сделать в 4 действия:

1. создать новый столбец типа INTEGER
2. записать в него данные из столбца типа TEXT с использованием CAST и REPLACE, чтоб убрать запятые
3. удалить старый столбец
4. переименовать новый

Но можно ли всё сделать проще?

Comment: Поле типа текст реплейснуть на цифры без запятых, чтобы были только INT. Изменить тип поля на INT. По идее должно работать

Answer (score -1):

Всё можно сделать как Вы написали. Либо чуток намудрить, предварительно забекапив табличку))), с MODIFY COLUMN + CAST REPLACE

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name INTEGER USING CAST(REPLACE(column_name, ',', '') AS INTEGER);
```

Comment: Вот не знаю, где Вы выкопали такой синтаксис... но MySQL стопудово будет на него ругаться ошибкой.

Comment: Минуточку, обоснуйте что именно нельзя писать? ALTER TABLE и MODIFY COLUMN для изменения типа столбца таблицы,  функция CAST для преобразования текстового значения столбца в целое число. Внутри функции CAST используем REPLACE для удаления запятых из значения столбца перед его преобразованием в целое число.

Comment: Разве что INTEGER на INT или BIGINT заменить

Comment: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING CAST(REPLACE(num2, ',', '') AS INTEGER)' at line 1
`

Comment: *обоснуйте что именно нельзя писать?* Да чего тут обосновывать-то? [ALTER TABLE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) - никакого MODIFY COLUMN .. USING нет и в помине. Не, писать-то можно, вот только серверу глубоко плевать на придуманный кем-то синтаксис, ибо у него свой уже есть.